# Trying to connect an Azure Enterprise subscription to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

I'm simply trying to add my Azure Enterprise subscription to Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I go into Cloud Explorer, Add an Account, input my corporate email address and the box simply goes away.

Here's a quick screencast: http://www.screencast.com/t/DcKWQjIqn

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Can you log into the portal normally? (with the same credentials)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to download your publish profile from below link

https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings

when you want to publish your app to Azure, instead of login. import the profile file